# Rspec run before block once before multiple it blocks

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a `context` block in rspec with multiple `it` blocks inside it. I want to run a before block to set up data for the `it` blocks but this data takes a long time to set up and is being used to read only. rspec `before(:each)` creates and deletes this data after every it block which takes a long time. `before(:all)` creates the data at the start of all the tests and doesn't delete it.

Is there any way I can have this data created just within the `context` block and deleted after?

Comment: Have you tried using an `after(:all)` block to clean the data up when you're done? It sounds like you have a `before(:all)` working where it's setup, and you only need the tear down. This is what's mentioned in the first answer below, but using the different alias (`:context` instead of `:all`)

Answer (score 3):

Since RSpec 3 these are officially named `before/after(:{example,context})` (see [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks)).

What you want to accomplish can be done with a `before(:context)` where you set up the data and an `after(:context)` where you clean it up.

```rb
RSpec.describe Thing do
  before(:context) do
    @thing = Thing.new
  end

  after(:context) do
    @thing.delete
  end

  it "has 0 widgets" do
    expect(@thing.widgets.count).to eq(0)
  end

  it "can accept new widgets" do
    @thing.widgets << Object.new
  end

  it "shares state across examples" do
    expect(@thing.widgets.count).to eq(1)
  end
end
```